# Validate Bool using Fluent Validator

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluentvalidation

I want to validate a bool property using fluent validator.
Which method should I use?

.NotNull() and .NotEmpty() functions didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you validate in boolean? It cannot go bad, it cannot be null (unless null-able and you still use `NotNull()`?

Comment: I have a combobox and want to validate if is any item selected. But, if nothing is selected, is comes false :(

Comment: You say you tried Equal() but are you sure it wasn't Equals()? I had the same issue, Equals() did not work but Equal() did.

Answer (score 16):

You should use `.NotNull()`.

`NotEmpty()` will take only `true` as valid property. `NotNull()` will take both `true` and `false` as valid properties.

Comment: NotNull seems to work well with false input on my localhost but unexpectedly return 'Is Enabled' must not be empty on Azure

Answer (score 5):

In order to validate a boolean using fluent validator:

Create the following rule

```
            RuleFor(x => x.BooleanProperty)
            .Must(ValidateBoolean)
            .WithErrorCode("Boolean Validation Failed");
```

Define the predicate validator

```
        private bool ValidateBoolean(T arg1, bool arg2, PropertyValidatorContext arg3)
    {
        // validate arg2, return true if validation successful or false if failed
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808794/validate-checkbox-on-the-client-with-fluentvalidation-mvc-3). Its successfully answered and I guess this is what you're looking for.

In it they create fluent validator to check if `@Html.CheckBox` is selected. If i understood your question, this is exactly what you're looking for.

Please let me know if that helps. - Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using `.Equal(true)` - That outta do it.