# ASP MVC3 FluentValidation on format field

Tags: c#, client-side, fluentvalidation

I have a registration page where the user registerer by email.
So fot the model I have a validation rule that states:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Common.WrongEmail"));
```

The problem now is that I have a demand that states that based on a setting we want to restirct this to a email with specific domain.

I did this simply by doing a regex validation

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email).Matches(customerSettings.RestrictLoginPattern).WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Customer.Fields.Email.EnteredPasswordWrongFormat"));
```

So if the email does not match a regex then a errormessage is displayed. So far so good.

The second specification is that the user should be able to not submit the domain. So for *user.name@test.com* the user should be able to write just *user.name*

I did this by doing a get/set for the email property

```
    public string Email { 
        set
        {
            _email = value;
        }

        get
        {
            if (_email == null)
                return null;

            if(!_email.EndsWith(LoginSuffix))
            {
                return string.Format("{0}{1}", _email, LoginSuffix);
            }
            return _email;
        }
```

So if i write something that does not ends with *test.com* it's added.
The problem now is that this does not happend on the client-side so the validation displays an error that the email is not well formated.

I tried to remove the get feature from Email and added a property FormatedEmail that I did validate. Since FormatedEmail is not on form clientside works fine, but when it not validates I can't get the error to *hook* to email field, just as a summary error

I see multiple solution

I can disable the clientside validation for just that field. But based on searches I find that that's probably not possible?

I can write a custom clientside validation, but that feels like quite complex for such a "small" matter.

There is a way to bind an error to a field somehow?

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Error message");
```

Comment: Sigh...sounds like stupid requirements to be honest. Anyways. Have you considered that you are trying too hard with a SINGLE rule? Have you considered splitting these "requirements" into separate "rules". Since from my point of view `requirement = rule`.

Comment: How do I do that? I need to make sure that the entered text + suffix is validated as an email, and if not, I would like to show validationmessage to the email field. It should also be ok to write full email and the suffix is "ignored".

Comment: Check out this for integration client side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808794/validate-checkbox-on-the-client-with-fluentvalidation-mvc-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I find the concept of business logic in getter/setters to be abhorrent. As a developer, I expect that the following should always work.

```
var foo = {something};
var bar = new Bar{ Baz = foo };
Assert.AreEqual(foo, bar.Baz);
```

The code you included in my opinion is what I would call "magical".

Anyways.

I would try to split out the different validation rules.

```
public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Email)
            .Matches(customerSettings.RestrictLoginPattern)
            .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Customer.Fields.Email.EnteredPasswordWrongFormat"))
            //When User is a full email address
            //Make sure its a valid email address
            .When(x => x.Contains('@') || x.EndsWith("@yourdomain.com"));

        RuleFor(x => x.Email)
            .Matches(InternalUsernamePattern)
            .WithMessage("foobaz")
            //Username does not contain @
            //Internal user rules!
            .Unless(x => x.Contains('@')|| x.EndsWith("@yourdomain.com"));
    }

}
```

Comment: BTW. Rule number 1 with Client Side Validation. Never trust the client. If you do go for Client Side Validation back it up with Server-Side. It is due to this rule that frameworks like node.js are becoming very popular. It allows you to write the same validation model once and run it both server and client side.

Comment: Of course I don't trust Client side validation, but see it as a good user interface to have the user know what to put in where. Your tip with the .When is good and I will try that. If it also works with clientside (or is ignored by clientside for email field) it is a good solution I think. I'm kind of new to the FluentValidators so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was to take Arons tips and create rules for only the email and when i have the suffix settings active, do a manually validation of the email with suffix that it is a valid email.

```
if (_customerSettings.FixedSuffix && !model.Email.EndsWith(_customerSettings.LoginSuffix))
{
   if (!ValidationHelper.IsEmail(string.Format("{0}{1}", model.Email, _customerSettings.LoginSuffix)))
      ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Not a valid email with suffix {0}", _customerSettings.LoginSuffix));
   else
      model.Email = string.Format("{0}{1}", model.Email, _customerSettings.LoginSuffix);  // add the suffix to the email for user creation 
}
```

FluedValidation of email uses this regex (http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1448) for email so I created a helper to validate.

I still can't set the message to the email field, but it is displayed in the summary.